# ObjectListView loop through items and delete selected

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to count selected items and delete selected items with a loop by using an [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) (found on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/)). What I have is not working

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If lstObjectMain.Items.Count > 0 Then
        If lstObjectMain.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Debug.Print(lstObjectMain.SelectedItems.Count)
            lstObjectMain.SelectedItem.Remove()
        End If            
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean this [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html)?

Comment: yes thats the only ObjectListView I know of

Comment: I added a link to the `ObjectListView` project page on sourceforge to your question. Since this control is not included in the .NET Framework libraries most people don't know what you are talking about. By the way, this control looks really cool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
If lstObjectMain.SelectedObjects IsNot Nothing Then
    For Each a In lstObjectMain.SelectedObjects
        lstObjectMain.RemoveObject(a)
    Next
End If
```

Keep in mind that this is only removing items from the view. 
It is better to modify underlying model, and then hit again `lstObjectMain.SetObjects()`

Comment: that will not work. it will throw an exception as the collection would have been modified whilst you are iterating through it.

Comment: Please try first Ahmed

Comment: I certainly tried and got the error... but I see the post is not edited ;)

Comment: Well, it is working for me. Must have worked for him as well, since he marked this as answer.